# asymptotics of tricomi function

Tags: special-functions

What's the asymptotic behavior of the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function $U(a,b,z)$ when $|z|\to0$ and $b$ is complex but with $Re(b)=1$. The Abramowitz and Stegun handbook does not seem to include this case; They have the cases when $Re(b)>1$ and when $b=1$, meaning when $b$ is purely real. Any references?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of formulas for $U(a,b,z)$ at the [Wolfram function site](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/). The simplest for $z\rightarrow 0$ is this
$$U(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a-b+1)}\Big(1+(O(z)\Big)+ \frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}z^{1-b}\Big(1+O(z)\Big), \;b\not \in \mathbb{Z}, z\rightarrow 0.$$
Other cases for $b\not \in \mathbb{Z}$ are in the section 
[General case](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/06/01/03/01/)
and for $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ see the entries in [Logarithmic case](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/06/01/03/02/).